# I am printing only map with markers and polylines from my webpage, marker is printed but polylines is not going to print.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, iframe

I am printing only map with markers and polylines from my webpage, marker is printed but polylines is not going to print.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div> <!-- map id , which is initialized on page load-->
    <!-- iframe for print -->
    <iframe name="field_map" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    <!-- end -->
    <script>
    function printMap(){
        window.frames["field_map"].document.body.innerHTML=$("#map").html();
        window.frames["field_map"].window.focus();
        window.frames["field_map"].window.print();
        return;
    };
    </script>
    <body>
    </html
```

Comment: Google Maps and any other maps use canvas to draw their maps, the elements you are missing from the print are in another layer/canvas (like an overlay), so you are printing one and the other not. Can you show us in a fiddle or something a real example with dummy data.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am initializing map on page onload and marker or polylines is drawing on an event. simply i am using markerwithlabel google api, and for polylines "new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions)".